# MariaDB localhost failure with docker compose while healthcheck

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm working on Debian-based Virtual Box

I have docker-compose yaml file:

```yaml
version: '3' 
services:
  mydb:
    build: ./db/
    networks:
      - dockercompose-frontend 
    volumes:
      - server_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debian
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mariadb-admin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 5

  frontend:
    build: .
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      networks:
        - dockercompose-frontend
      environment:
        PMA_HOST=mydb
        PMA_PORT=3306

volumes:
  server_db:
    driver: local
networks:
  dockercompose-frontend:
```

And two Dockerfiles for each of the services, where I just install necessary images.

```
FROM mariabd:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

and

```
FROM phpmyadmin:5.2.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

When I'm using `docker compose up` (without -d mode):

```
frontend-1 | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain nam e, using 172.25.0.2. Set the ServerName directive globally to suppress this message
```

When I'm using `docker compose up -d` and checks Health State for mydb it throws:

```
{
  "Status":"starting", 
  "FailingStreak": 2, 
  "Log": [{"Start": "2024-02-19T10:05:48.178379963-05:00",
    "End": 2024-02-19T10:05:48.240662846-05:00", 
    "ExitCode": 1, 
    "Output":"\u0007mariadb-admin: connect to server a t 'localhost failed\nerror: 'Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2) 
    'Check that mariadbd is running and that the socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!"
}
```

Also,

```
docker exec dockercompose-mydb-1 service mariadb status
```

throws "Mariadb service is stopped"

After

```
docker exec dockercompose-mydb-1 service mariadb start
```

it throws exit code 1 (failure).

Answer (score 1):

### first, update the syntax in health check part as there's error with quotes to

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "mariadb-admin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 15s
  retries: 5
```

### second specify the port in mariadb service

```
version: '3' 
services:
  mydb:
    build: ./db/
    networks:
      - dockercompose-frontend 
    volumes:
      - server_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debian
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mariadb-admin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s 
      timeout: 15s 
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"  # Map container's port 3306 to host's port 3306

  frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - dockercompose-frontend
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mydb
      PMA_PORT: 3306

volumes:
  server_db:
    driver: local
#rest of your docker comopse file
```

### also make sure that the network driver is not equal to none, it's type is equal to bridge for example.

#### you can add "depends_on" in frontend service so the container is not created unless mariaDB is up successfully.

```
  frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - dockercompose-frontend
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mydb
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    depends_on:
      - mydb  # to prevent docker compose from starting the container until the container of mariaDB is running.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Also I add `MYSQL_DATABASE=example_database`, but now I have another issue.
State is now "healthy", but Healthcheck logs returns: "Access denied for user root @ localhost". How is that possible?

Comment: @DeBug this is due to user privileges in MariaDB, check whether there's ENV that can fix that, or you can fix that using SQL command, I'm not expert in SQL commands but try this one:              GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON example_database.* TO 'root'@'localhost';

Answer (score 0):

There's a [healthcheck.sh](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh-script/) script  for the very purpose.

```
test:[ "CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized" ]
```

So there's no need to additional grants, users to make this happen.

The other problem with `mariadb-admin ping` is without `--protocol tcp` it can return healthly during the initialization phases of the startup.